# MacBook Pro new battery not charging. Defective?

Tags: macos, hardware, battery

Model: MacBook Pro 13" Retina early 2015

My MacBook Pro had a battery in the condition "Replace now" so I bought a new battery on ebay and got it replaced. The problem is the MacBook identifies the battery but it is in the condition of "Replace now" and does not go above 0%. It was with 0% when I installed it since when I connected the power adapter the computer turned on.

- I reset SMC and PRAM.
- I'm almost sure my power adapter is fine and I can use the computer with the power adapter.

I'm thinking I purchased a dead battery and that is the problem?
What else could be the problem?

If you could give me your opinion on the battery stats on the image attached would help a lot.

[image: Stats]

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-sg/exchange_repair see at the end if any recall programme you can find useful.

Comment: Get a refund. Batteries on eBay are going to be a 'variable quality', to say the least. 

Well done on replacing it yourself, though: that's hardcore!

Comment: This model is not elegible for a replacement.. but I believe it surfer from the same battery problem. Apple asked for an outrageous price for a replacement.

Comment: Already for my refund

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That certainly looks like a dead battery.  [iFixit sells a replacement kit](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13%22-Retina-Early-2015/Batteries) starting at $99 (USD).

Comment: Is recall programme an alternative.. I think I read it somewhere..

Comment: tbh, if you just bought it, send it straight back, don't buy another & have a dud to dispose of.

Comment: I'm in Europe so it's a bit more expensive. Are Ifixit batteries good quality? Any guarantee?

Comment: I've never used an iFixit replacement battery, but they have a good reputation and I have bought plenty of other tools and parts.